# Class comparison, isKindOfClass not working in Kiwi spec

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, kiwi

Is there some reason my Kiwi unit tests are failing with these two lines:

```
[[theValue([editAuthorViewController class] == [EditAuthorViewController class]) should] beYes];

[[theValue([editAuthorViewController isKindOfClass:[EditAuthorViewController class]]) should] beYes];
```

While this line passes?

```
NSString *classString = NSStringFromClass([editAuthorViewController class]);
[[classString should] equal:@"EditAuthorViewController"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out there's a Kiwi expression to test this I wasn't aware of.

```
[[editAuthorViewController should] beKindOfClass:[EditAuthorViewController class]];
```

This failed initially because my `EditAuthorViewController.m` file was added to my test target. Since `[EditAuthorViewController class`] was returning a different pointer when called from inside the test bundle, the comparison failed.

To fix this, I had to remove `EditAuthorViewController.m` from my Compile Sources in my test target.

Comment: I haven't ever used Kiwi, but from what I infer from above... it should work as isKindOfClass returns a BOOL, same as the above line.

Comment: I was able to get all of the above lines working by removing `EditAuthorViewController.m` from my Compile Sources in my test target. There's a great explanation of the problem and solution here: http://www.objc.io/issue-1/testing-view-controllers.html under "Side Note About Classes and Injection".